# JSP : Evoking a java code

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, web-applications

I was just introduced to JSP 3 days ago so I'm still not very familiar with it.

So I have this code here :

```html
<body>
        <form method="post">
            <center>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Login Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
        </form>
```

Note : This code was borrowed from the internet. I'll be changing it once I'm done with connecting this to mySQL. Credits to Lahaul Seth.

So I was wondering how I can evoke the code below.

```
String username = request.getParameter("username");
String password = request.getParameter("password");

if(Login.LoginA(username, password).equals("Admin")){
        out.println("Admin");
}else if(Login.LoginA(username, password).equals("Employee")){
        out.println("Employee");
}else{
    out.println("Unidentified User");
}
```

I think I have to do something with the login button in the html part, but I have no idea how. Hope you guys can help me.
Thank you!

Comment: Invest some time to read the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html).

Comment: I tried but I still can't understand it very well. I though that if I got an idea on how it actually works I'd be able to understand the tutorial better. So I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Please add a action attribute on form tag as below :

```
<form method="post" action="LoginServlet">
            <center>
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2">
                <thead> 
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Login Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="username" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Login" />
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
                        </td>                        
                    </tr>                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>
        </form>
```

create one servlet mention like this which will read the username and password based on name attribute of input tag as mentioned below

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String user_name =request.getParameter("username");
    String password =request.getParameter("password");
    System.out.println("Username -> "+user_name +" Password --> "+password);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should add more information if you want to explain him how to use a Servlet.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll try my best to understand this.